# how to capture two pictures on one button click - one with front and one with back camera

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which I need to capture two pictures, one with front camera and other from back camera.

The code that I am using for this purpose is given below, this code works fine when I take only one picture with front or back camera, but when I capture two pictures (one after other) I am getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service` at `camera = Camera.open(camIdx);` call.

I have been searching for solution to this problem since two days but have failed to solve it. I double checked to `release()` the `camera` after first photo being capture in order make camera free for second photo but nothing works.

I am using physical device for testing which has Android KitKat version (API level 19).

So please tell what is issue in my code? Or is there any alternate way to get my job done?

**Code:**

```
package com.example.appdeveloper.appname;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    static Camera camera = null;
    static int pic_number = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        takeSnapShots(this,Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
        takeSnapShots(this,Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
    }


    private void takeSnapShots(Context context, int face) {

        SurfaceView surface = new SurfaceView(context);
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        int cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == face) {
                camera = Camera.open(camIdx);
            }
        }

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        camera.startPreview();
        camera.takePicture(null,null,jpegCallback);
    }




    private static Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera1) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ File.separator+"picure"+(++pic_number)+".jpg";
            File pictureFile = new File(path);

            if (pictureFile.exists())
                pictureFile.delete();

            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.setRotate(90);
                realImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(realImage, 0, 0, realImage.getWidth(), realImage.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                realImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
            }
        }
    };




}
```

Comment: try to add two surface 
generally try to do everything 2 times. define 2 instance of camera object and 2 surface view, so on.

Comment: @EliasFazel I have tried this already.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably trying to open the second camera without releasing the first. You call `Camera.open` in a loop, without releasing first. The correct flow is to open the camera you want, take the picture, make sure the camera is released and then open the other camera.

Comment: Please read my answer again. I saw where you released it - but you are trying to open the two cameras in a loop, without releasing. Your release is only after the picture is taken.